# Determing the Two Closest Vertices a Point Lies Between on Circumcircle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry

For a computational geometry application, I need to determine the two closest vertices that a point lies between on a circle that has been sliced into angular intervals.

To illustrate the problem, consider the crudely drawn diagram below. The circle that bounds the polygon is intersected at points by the line segments (green) that extrude from the polygon's vertices (red), yielding a set of angles.

[image: imgur]

Now suppose that a point(x,y) is placed at random on the circle (as in the diagram above with the orange dot) so that it lies between two red vertices. What is the fastest method for finding which two red vertices p lies between?

I know that a binary search over the array of vertices on the circle will work but am curious as to whether there is an analytical solution.

The motivation for solving this problem is to relate a given point to the convex polygon: to determine whether the point intersects or is interior to any of the triangles of the polygon.

Comment: Unless the angles follow some simple pattern (such as being uniformly spaced), you aren't going to beat binary search.  Any motivation for hoping otherwise?

Comment: In my application, I am performing a 2D simulation where there are thousands of n-vertex polygons, specified by thousands of vertices on the convex hull.  When two polygon's might be colliding I need to determine if p makes contact with one of these edges.

Comment: Ok, but log(thousands) is only 13 or so.  Does the simulation last for many frames using the same set of polygons, so that you might hope to invest precalculation time on each polygon to speed up subsequent point locations?  Maybe integrate that level of detail into your question so that it's easier to decide what "fastest" means.

Comment: The polygons are subject to high velocities. To check if two polygons collide, their position vectors are computed from their instantaneous velocities with respect to a change in time, dt. When dt is chosen to be small more collision detection tests are required but when dt chosen too large polygons may pass through one another or escape the visible universe...